# Show the inequality $1-2F(x) \leq P(X+Y>2x) \leq 2(1-F(x))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem is stated in the following image:

[image]

I've proved the RHS of the inequality (I think at least), but I'm unsure whether my first step in this solution is correct. Although I managed to "prove" it, I still feel that the step I made is a bit unrigorous and "risky", and maybe someone out there can explain whether (and why) this step is correct.

**Solution:**

First, we realize that $X+Y > 2x \Rightarrow X > 2x \cup Y > 2x$. Meaning that (this is the step that I'm unsure of)

$$P(X+Y > 2x) = P(X > 2x \cup Y > 2x) = P(X > 2x) + P(Y>2x) - P(X > 2x \cap Y>2x) \leq P(X>2x) + P(Y>2x) = 1 - F(2x) + 1-F(2x) = 2 - 2F(2x) \leq 2 - 2F(x) = 2(1-F(x))$$

For the second part, I tried using the same reasoning above, but with these steps:

$$P(X+Y > 2x) = P(X > 2x \cup Y > 2x) = P(X > 2x) + P(Y>2x) - P(X > 2x \cap Y>2x) \geq P(X>2x) + P(Y>2x) -1 = 1 - F(2x) + 1-F(2x) - 1 = 1 - 2F(2x)$$

Which then finishes the proof for the RHS, and "almost" for the LHS. I really don't know what last step I could use in order to finish it off for the LHS.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if $X=1.5x$ and $Y=1.5x$? Then $X+Y>2x$ but neither $X$ nor $Y$ are larger than $2x$.

Comment: @angryavian Good point! I just came to think of that, so instead I thought I could use that $X > x \cap Y > x$. But I'm unsure if this is correct, since this doesn't cover all scenarios. I could've choosen $ X = 0.1x$ and $Y = 1.9x$ for instance. I don't really see an easy way to cover all the scenarios for $X + Y  > 2x$ by splitting this up into a union / intersection of two events for $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modification of your first step: $X+Y>2x \implies \{X>x\} \cup \{Y > x\}$.

Then, by the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality),
$$P(X+Y>2x) \le P(\{X>x\} \cup \{Y > x\}) \le  P(X > x) + P(Y > x) = 2(1-F(x)).$$

---

For the reverse, direction use $X+Y \le 2x \implies \{X \le x\} \cup \{Y \le x\}$ and apply a similar argument.

Comment: Thank you. This made it clear for me.